# Visibility binding fails

Tags: visibility, mvvmcross

I try to use the Visibility plugin with the FieldBinding plugin with no luck.

Model side:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the birthdate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The birthdate.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

ViewModel side:

```
public class DisplayUserViewModel : BaseUserViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The user
    /// </summary>
    public readonly INC<User> User = new NC<User>();
}
```

View side, first try:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTileHeight"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginRight"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility User.Birthdate, Converter=Visibility">
```

Second try:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTileHeight"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginRight"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(User.Birthdate)">
```

But same result:

```
MvxBind ( 2574):  33.60 Failed to create target binding for binding Visibility for MvxValueConverterValueCombiner combiner-operation
```

I just took the birthdate as an example, but every Visibility bindings failed (I have x error messages for x bindings).

---

**EDIT 1**

The others binding work, I bind a bunch of text, and all display well:

```
      <TextView
         style="@style/TextView.ListWithIcon.Single"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginTop"
         local:MvxBind="Text User.FirstName" />
```

I also try to bind to a INPC property, same result.

---

**EDIT 2**

As suggested by stuart, i tried this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TextView.ListWithIcon.Single"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginTop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ListIconTextMarginLeft"
    local:MvxBind="Text Visibility(User.Birthdate)">
```

And the visibility converter on TextView seems to work, if Birthdate is null:

```
Birthdate:  Gone
```

But it does not seem to bind to the visibility property:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TextView.ListWithIcon.SecondLine"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Birthday"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(User.Birthdate)"
    android:text="Whatever birthdate" />
```

Displays "Whatever birthdate" whereas Visibility(User.Birthdate) returns Gone...

---

**EDIT 3**

If you use Visible pseudo-property everything works as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTileHeight"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginRight"
            local:MvxBind="Visible User.Birthdate">
```

Comment: Can't comment from the content here. Are there any more error messages or warnings? The one you get is from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bbf9a2ac76e74d9404f4b57036c6e29dfe2cc6c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/MvxFullBinding.cs#L139 but I'd expect/hope for more. Some experiments to try: Does the binding work if you use INPC instead? Does the binding work if you a property other than Visibility (e.g. if you bind to Text in a test TextView)? Best to edit the question if you can - answering in comments is harder to read...

Comment: Unfortunately I have just the errors above (one more edited). Is there an option to have a more verbose log ?

Comment: "Does the binding work if you use INPC instead? Does the binding work if you a property other than Visibility (e.g. if you bind to Text in a test TextView)?" - maybe try changing one thing at a time - i.e if you change your text view to `<TextView
         style="@style/TextView.ListWithIcon.Single"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ListIconTwoLineTextMarginTop"
         local:MvxBind="Text Visibility(User.Birthdate)" />` and then `local:MvxBind="Text User.Birthdate"` then that might give you some clues - is the problem INC, Visibilty, the `DateTime?`, or something else...

Comment: I tried again and added a second edit in my question.

Comment: in that case... I have no real idea - it looks like the value converter is working. Does the sample in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/View_Visibility.axml work for you? Does it work if you switch to using a binding for `mvxBind="Visible User.Birthdate"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsLoading)">
```

Visibility of the LinearLayout wouldn't bind to my view model:

> Failed to create target binding for binding Visibility for MvxValueConverterValueCombiner combiner-operation

Solution: add an entry to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs so the Visibility property isn't stripped from the view:

```
public void Include(LinearLayout layout)
{
    layout.Click += (s, e) => layout.Visibility = layout.Visibility - 1;
}
```

Comment: yup ! I suspected this kind of issues, but I didn't think about the property itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 scenarios:

1. If you use MvvmCross 5 and below you need to use:

a) `local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(User.Birthdate)"` in your view

b) add a VisibilityPluginBootstrap.cs file in you Bootstrap folder that would look like this:

```
 using MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins;
    
    namespace YourNameSpace.Droid.Bootstrap
    {
        public class VisibilityPluginBootstrap
            : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader>
        {
        }
    }
```

[image]

2. If you use MvvmCross 6 and above you need to use only:

   `local:MvxBind="Visible User.Birthdate"` in your view

and don't need a Bootstrap file:

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I used Visibility plugin with early versions and back then sintax was different ->  local:MvxBind="Visibility ActiveTab==1, Converter=Visibility" . This plugin really works with Visible but I wonder how to use InvertedVisibility converter with MvvmCross 6 + sintax